# Slow API Data Retrieval Despite Using Pagination

Tags: apache-spark, databricks

I've utilized the following script to fetch data from an API. However, retrieving just 18,000 records takes nearly three minutes. I've experimented with adjusting the LIMIT parameter, but it doesn't seem to help. What could be the reason behind this? I'm working in Databricks:

```
import requests

def fetch_qualification_data():
    base_url = "https://linktoapi"
    qualification_data = []
    limit = 1000  # Setting the limit
    offset = 0

    while True:
        parameters = {
            'limit': limit,
            'offset': offset,
            'with': 'sets,sets.effects,texts'
        }
        response = requests.get(base_url, params=parameters)
        if response.status_code == 200:
            data_page = response.json()
            # Directly checking the type of data_page to adapt to unexpected data structure
            if isinstance(data_page, list):
                received_data = data_page
            elif isinstance(data_page, dict) and 'data' in data_page:
                received_data = data_page['data']
            else:
                print("Unexpected data structure.")
                break
            
            qualification_data.extend(received_data)
            if len(received_data) < limit:
                break
            offset += limit
        else:
            print(f"Error while fetching data: {response.status_code}")
            break

    return qualification_data

data = fetch_qualification_data()
print(f"Fetched {len(data)} records.")
```

**In this script, I'm fetching data from an API using pagination. Despite setting the pagination parameters, the data retrieval process remains slow. What could I do to optimize this process?**